# Should we use collection, get and sets?

Tags: java, performance, getter-setter

I was reading a java book, where it said that when accessing/modifying  to variables in different class it should be use the get/set methods to manipulate them.

My question is, overtime and in big projects using gets/sets will not jeopardize the application performance?

Similar question, typically should we preferable use arrays in detriment of more abstract data type (such likened list of instance), since array are normally more cache friendly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless you're writing some critical section of a high-efficient algorithm that must run in some embedded device, your first goal should be to produce simple, readable, maintainable code. OOP helps us in this regard with some features like encapsulation. Getters and setters allow encapsulating some behavior. They're also a standard used by several Java technologies (like the JSP EL, various scripting languages, IDEs, etc.). The performance should not be the primary design factor in general.

Java just in time compilers are really smart, and will inline the calls to the getters and setters.

Higher-level abstractions like Java collections also help writing simpler and safer code, and have been tested and optimized. Reimplementing all they provide with arrays would lead to hard-to-maintain, inefficient code. Definitely use the Java collections and prefer them over arrays.

Remember that efficient incorrect code is useless compared to a bit slower correct code.

Answer (score 2):

> My question is, overtime and in big projects using gets/sets will not
>   jeopardize the application performance?

Nope. It promotes data encapsulation and is a good OO practice.

> Software objects are conceptually similar to real-world objects: they
>   too consist of state and related behavior. An object stores its state
>   in fields (variables in some programming languages) and exposes its
>   behavior through methods (functions in some programming languages).
>   Methods operate on an object's internal state and serve as the primary
>   mechanism for object-to-object communication. *Hiding internal state
>   and requiring all interaction to be performed through an object's
>   methods is known as **data encapsulation** — a fundamental principle of
>   object-oriented programming.*

from the [Java Trail](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/object.html) .

> Should we preferable use arrays in detriment of more abstract data
>   type (such likened list of instance), since array are normally more
>   cache friendly.

This depends on your use case.
  I think by cache friendly you mean more memory efficient.
There will be some fragmentation involved while removing elements and also arrays are designed with a certain initial capacity. In `ArrayList` it starts with 10 and then continuously re-sized according to your needs.

But, the good part about using an Array is that you can access elements by index.

Answer (score 1):

The word is Encapsulation. Using `get` and `set` makes it easier to control access to the variables (say, check that the values are in range, synchronization, control when they are changed -useful for race conditions in concurrent programming-, that the thread using them has permissions to do so, etc.). Specially for big projects, this is more important than a tiny overhead.

Also, `get` and `set` are in definition of Java beans, which are used by a number of frameworks (JPA, JSF, and so on).

Arrays are ok, but if you do not know the exact size of your array, then either you are going to waste memory in empty cells or will have to resize them often, adding complexity to your code.

Answer (score 1):

I can't remember the last time I used an array in Java. I always use a collection like `ArrayList` or similar. Arrays are more used when you're working with raw bytes like images. Internally a collection is implemented using arrays, so it's basically the same with additional methods like `add`, `put`, `get`, remove, etc.

Answering the `getter/setter` question, you MUST use getters and setters if you're writing a library that will be used by other people. The interface or layer that the users will use should not be accessed through simple properties (`new A().property`), it's a very bad design because you're not encapsulating anything. Even if your module it's private and only used by your application you MUST use `getters/setters` in the front-end layer. If a class is internal and cannot be accessed from outside the module/package then it's ok to access it through properties but it's preferable to encapsulate. The only case where I access through properties is when I have a private class inside a public class. I access to the private class from the public using properties. Example:

```
public class A{
    B b = new B ();

    private class B{
        String asd = "asd";
    }

    public String a (){
        return b.asd;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're building a data object whose sole purpose is to have fields to get and set, then getters and setters are a good idea.  They let you validate and synchronize if necessary, and even change fields around without breaking old code (by just changing the fields and keeping the API constant).

In most if not all other cases, though, getters and setters are a *bad* idea.  The problem doesn't even have anything to do with performance.  The problem is that outside of those aforementioned data objects, **getters and setters break encapsulation almost as badly as exposing the underlying variables themselves directly.**  If you *have* to have visible variables, then use get/set methods; in most cases, though, you don't have to have visible variables.

A consumer should not care, or in most cases even *know*, about the variables a class contains.  That is the essence of encapsulation -- not this misguided notion of "hide variables behind getters", but "hide variables, *period*".  You definitely should not be *setting* them; it is the class's responsibility to manage its variables, and if the user has to set the class's operating parameters for it before using it, then the class is broken.  If the caller has to `getAnything()` after calling your method, then the method signature is wrong; *that stuff they're getting should have been a return value*.

Exposing a member variable at all, whether via a getter/setter or just by making the field public, should only be considered if that field is data.  Every other situation calls for better encapsulation.

As for arrays vs collections, that depends on the circumstances.  I personally like using collections when both make sense, but that's a personal preference.  Things like cache locality and such should not be your primary concerns when deciding on this.  Keep in mind, though, that an `ArrayList` is just as cache-friendly as a plain old array in most cases.  If you define stuff to take and return `List`s, then you can switch out List subtypes pretty much at will as you find a particular subtype now suits your needs better.  Just you try switching your API's array return value to a linked list without breaking existing code.  :)